# Redirect subdomain to specific URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, subdomain

I've seen hundred of examples, but I can't adapt them to my case.

I need to redirect (via htaccess) from radio.mysite.com:8000 to www.mysite.com:8000/radio.pls

Can somebody help please? Thanks!!

EDIT: I tried several things, but most like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^radio\.mysite\.com:8000$ --// I also tried without the port which would be fine
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.mysite.com:8000/radio.pls [L] --// I don't know what the [L] is for
```

The result is: with the 8000 port it does nothing, which I think is because htaccess (apache) work only on port 80 (is this right?). And without the 8000 port it just shows me some page that I don't know where it is (is a welcome page like when you purchase the hosting) but it's not my index or something like that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The port will be in the variable `%{HTTP_PORT}`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Match non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# Match port 8000
RewriteCond %{HTTP_PORT} ^8000
# And redirect to www with the correct port with the [R] flag
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.mysite.com:8000/radio.pls [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but it's not working. I set this up and try http://radio.mysite.com:8000 and it gives me 404 error, while http://www.mysite.com:8000/radio.pls works...

Comment: @Diego Since this is a redirect, not an internal rewrite, the script radio.pls has to actually be available on the document root that www.mysite.com is accessing. You say mysite.com:8000/radio.pls works, but does www.mysite.com:8000/radio.pls work? if not, then you have to work out with your host where www. is pointing.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for answer! Actually, both www and non-www URLs are working ok, but not the redirection (radio.mysite...).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^radio\.mysite\.com$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_PORT} ^8000$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mysite.com:8000/radio.pls [R,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^radio\.mysite\.com$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_PORT} ^8000$
RewriteRule ^$ /radio.pls [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
*(Put this in the .htaccess file of the folder your subdomain is located in)*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.primarydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.primarydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.addondomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Switch it to no www. if you want that to be your primary domain.